# Cross section of the spherical projection using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

How can I draw a cross section of the spherical projection using tikz?

I tried graph using manual TikZ, but I did not succeed.

Any help?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! There are quite a few similar diagrams on this site. Now there is one more. Intersections can be found with the `intersections` library, braces with `decorations.pathreplacing` (and `calligraphy`), and the right angle symbols with the `angles` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mbrace/.style={decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,
    amplitude=7pt,raise=1ex},thick},
    dot/.style={circle,fill=red,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2.5pt}]
 \draw (-3,0) node[left]{$\mathds{C}$} -- (4.5,0);
 \draw[name path=circ] (0,0) node[dot,label=below:{$0$}] (O){} 
    circle[radius=2.5cm];
 \draw[name path=line] (0,2.5) node[dot,label=above:{$\zeta$}] (zeta) {}
    -- (4,0)node[dot,label=above:{$z$}] (z) {};
 \draw[name intersections={of=circ and line}] (intersection-2) node[dot,label=above
 right:{$z^*$}](z*){} (z*) -- (O|-z*) node[dot](h){} 
 (O) -- (zeta) (z*) edge[dashed] (O-|z*) (O-|z*)node[dot](z'){} ;   
 \draw[mbrace,decorate] (O) -- node[left=2ex] {$1$} (zeta);
 \draw[mbrace,decorate] (O-|z*) -- node[left=2ex] {$x_3$} (z*);
 \path[angle radius=4pt] pic[draw]{right angle = z'--O--zeta}
    pic[draw]{right angle = z*--h--zeta}
    pic[draw]{right angle = z--z'--z*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have some questions, is there a book to learn how to draw with Tikz? Will it be possible to draw fractals with Tikz?

Comment: @Halsey12 The pgfmanual is a very good resource. It has tutorials, and section **51.7 Fractal Decorations** of version 3.1.5 deals with fractals.

Comment: @Shrödinger's cat So could you build the Julia, Fatou and Mandelbrot sets?

Comment: @Halsey12 You can do a Google image search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com tizk fractals` to get an idea for what has been done, and what is possible. Please note also that, depending on the complexity, compilation time may be large, so if you have something really complex in mind, perhaps Ti*k*Z is not the appropriate tool.